# Using a customized bootstrap navbar, how do I make the mobile version look different from the desktop version

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navigation, navbar

I am struggling using bootstrap framework for my navigation bar.

Once I start to customize it the desktop version, the mobile version (collapsed) no longer displays as a dropdown mobile menu.

It looks just like my desktop menu when I expend it.

I'm assuming it is a simple solution, but I've researched for a while and can't figure it out.

```
<head>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet'  type='text/css'>

<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="portfolio.css">
</head>

<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"> 
 <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> 
 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
 <span class="icon-bar"></span>
 <span class="icon-bar"></span>

        </button> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>

    </div>
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Portfolio</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Credentials</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Resume</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Mentions</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

```
/* --- Style --- */
/* navbar */
.navbar-default {
    height: 90px;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
    border-color: #D6D6D6;
    text-align: center;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav {
    margin: 0;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav li {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 13%;
    float: none;
}

/* title */
.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
    font: 30px 'Pacifico', Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-style: normal;
    color: #616161;
    text-shadow: 1.5px 1.5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0.5px 0.5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    padding-top: 20px;

}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:focus {
    font: 30px 'Pacifico', Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-style: normal;
    color: green;
    text-shadow: 1.5px 1.5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0.5px 0.5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);

}
/* link */
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
    font-family: Open Sans, sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #3B3B3B; /* inactive link text color */
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 3px;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
    color: #3B3B3B; /* active link text color */
    font-weight: 600;
    background-color: #F5F5F5; /* inactive link bg color */
    box-shadow: inset 0px -6px 0px #EBEBEB; /* switch to a darker color on hover */
    padding-top: 3px;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a, 
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover, 
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
    color: #3B3B3B;
    font-weight: 600;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
    box-shadow: inset 0px -6px 0px 0px #00FFFF; /* switch to a lighter color for active element */
    padding-top: 3px;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a, 
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:hover, 
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a:focus {
    color: blue;
    background-color: red;
    padding-top: 3px;
}

}
/* mobile version */
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
    border-color: blue;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
    background-color: red;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
    background-color: green;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {

    .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a {
        color: red;
    }
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
    .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
        color: blue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello you need to a css media query and put the styles you want in it. what is the you need different?